# Reading Program Memory In AHK

Tags: memory, autohotkey, memory-address

So I am working on a program to read values from a game (Mitos.is: The Game).
It is similiar to [Agar.io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agar.io)

You have a size (mass), and I want to get the mass amount, it is a program, not an online game like Agar.io.

I have found this Auto Hotkey script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


ReadMemory(MADDRESS=0,PROGRAM="",BYTES=4)
{
   Static OLDPROC, ProcessHandle
   VarSetCapacity(MVALUE, BYTES,0)
   If PROGRAM != %OLDPROC%
   {
      WinGet, pid, pid, % OLDPROC := PROGRAM
      ProcessHandle := ( ProcessHandle ? 0*(closed:=DllCall("CloseHandle"
      ,"UInt",ProcessHandle)) : 0 )+(pid ? DllCall("OpenProcess"
      ,"Int",16,"Int",0,"UInt",pid) : 0)
   }
   If (ProcessHandle) && DllCall("ReadProcessMemory","UInt",ProcessHandle,"UInt",MADDRESS,"Str",MVALUE,"UInt",BYTES,"UInt *",0)
   {    Loop % BYTES
            Result += *(&MVALUE + A_Index-1) << 8*(A_Index-1)
        Return Result
    }
   return !ProcessHandle ? "Handle Closed:" closed : "Fail"
}


mass := ReadMemory(Address here, "Mitos.is: The Game")

MsgBox, %mass%
```

It works seamlessly but there is one slight problem, in Cheat Engine I took the liberty of finding the base address as shown below:
[image: Cheat Engine Base Address]

So I took the address circled here:[image: Red Circle]

And inserted that into the program where it says "Address Here", correct me if this is not the right address, but when I restart the game and run my script it says "Fail", but in Cheat Engine the address is still valid. Help?

Comment: Bump, anyone have an idea?

Comment: 16 views 1 upvote and no comments or replies :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the address if it changes after restarting the game, or do not restart game just run the script without restart and you haven't defined bytes so try following,

```
        ReadMemory(MADDRESS=0, PROGRAM="", BYTES=4 )
mass := ReadMemory("0x123456", "Mitos.is: The Game", "4")
```

"PROGRAM" should be correct window title use spy to get correct window title, address has to be in hex value i.e. "0x15B29DD0", I don't know how your cheat engine reads program memory address.